# How to design a 5-32 decoder using 4-16 decoder with enable?

Tags: digital-logic

I am finding it hard to find a detailed step by step process. Do I have to make a truth table?

Workings so far: I can guess that I would need 2 4-16 decoders, which share the 5 inputs of the required 5-32 decoder, and gives 32 outputs. **But that leaves me with 1 extra input that I can't cater to, where is it going to come from?**

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAvUZ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 5-bit decoder inputs.*

- Use the enable bit as the fifth bit.
- When '4' is low U1 is enabled.
- When '4' is high U2 is enabled.

Comment: Now you did the homework for @studious

Comment: Homework detector not switched on. Oops!

Comment: that's not 5-32, and it doesn't allow activating all the outputs as only one decoder is active at a time